# Python Operation on Column and "copy of a slice from a DataFrame" warning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that I divide into 2 subsets based on the values of one column (positive or negative).

Let's say one columns contains the following values:

```
1
4
9
2
1
```

I basically want to create a column in each subset computing the difference between the one value and the one just before.So it would give here something like this:

```
n/a
3
5
-7
-1
```

Then I just want to shift the value one row above. I used the code below that in the end gives me the result but I always get this warning that I don't understand.
"A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"
Can you please help?

```
df_left = df_s[df_s['Benchmark Sigma'] < 0]
df_right = df_s[df_s['Benchmark Sigma'] > 0]

df_left['Benchmark Sigma Interval'] = (df_left['Benchmark Sigma']-df_left['Benchmark Sigma'].shift(1))
df_right['Benchmark Sigma Interval'] = (df_right['Benchmark Sigma']-df_right['Benchmark Sigma'].shift(1))

df_left['Benchmark Sigma Interval']=df_left['Benchmark Sigma Interval'].shift(-1)
df_right['Benchmark Sigma Interval']=df_right['Benchmark Sigma Interval'].shift(-1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning is just letting you know that you may be modifying a copy of a df and not the original. In my experience, it's often a false positive. If you find this to be the case for you as well, you can turn off the warning.

For more information, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas), and especially the links @Garrett provided.